# JavaScript change empty form fields color

Tags: javascript, forms

I am doing some things to practice JavaScript.

I am making a form, and I want to "mark" empty fields with a red color and a text.

The code I have paints the inputs with red but just when I am clicking submit and then it goes white again. Other thing I can't do is to fill the empty field with text.

This is the script I am using (just for the color for now)

```
function validate() {
    var f1 = document.getElementById("name");
    var f2 = document.getElementById("email");
    var f3 = document.getElementById("address");
    var f4 = document.getElementById("age");
    var f5 = document.getElementById("cp");
    var ferror = [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < ferror.length; i++) {
        ferror[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    }
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I'm afraid that you haven't given us enough info to have any clue what your problem is.  If you edit your question and use the `snippet` ability, you can include the needed HTML to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there might be something else going on that is causing issues, but i added a conditional in the for loop that checks for value length on the input. You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/2Le9gzt4/

```
function validate() {
    var f1 = document.getElementById("name");
    var f2 = document.getElementById("email");
    var f3 = document.getElementById("address");
    var f4 = document.getElementById("age");
    var f5 = document.getElementById("cp");
    var ferror = [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < ferror.length; i++) {
      if(ferror[i].value.length < 1){
        ferror[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah it worked for me when I copy your form and script. But when I try with mine even on jsfiddle.net it says {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: I think there is more to your code that needs explaining. Would it be possible to share in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think I got it. I had something wrong in the form. I made a new one and it works just as you said in your previous post!

Comment: great glad to hear it. (feel free to mark this answer as the solution!)